# REST API multi-choice field return [object Object] instead of actual choice - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, office365, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I have a REST API which returns multi-choice field value as [object Object] instead of actual value.

**tableContent += '' + arrayOfAllData[i].Action_x0020_By_x003a_ + '';**

The field Action_x0020_By_x003a_ is a multi-choice field in Office365. I did try using arrayOfAllData[i].Action_x0020_By_x003a_.choices.results and also arrayOfAllData[i].Action_x0020_By_x003a_.results , but it returned undefined. Also used some map but doesnt work. Any advoice would be helpful

```html
<script src="https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SiteAssets/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var ListDataCollection = {
    Lists:[{
        Url:"https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/sites1/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items?$top=5&$orderby=Created desc&$select=Title,Description,Action_x0020_By_x003a_,RequestFrom_x003a_,Created&$filter=Category eq 'Key Events and Decision'",
        Completed:false
    },{
        Url:"https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/sites2/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items?$top=5&$orderby=Created desc&$select=Title,Description,Action_x0020_By_x003a_,RequestFrom_x003a_,Created&$filter=Category eq 'Key Events and Decision'",
        Completed:false
    },{
        Url:"https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/sites3/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items?$top=5&$orderby=Created desc&$select=Title,Description,Action_x0020_By_x003a_,RequestFrom_x003a_,Created&$filter=Category eq 'Key Events and Decision'",
        Completed:false
    }]
};
var tableContent = '<table id="tableEmployee" style="width:100%" border="1 px"><thead><tr><td><b>No</b></td>' + 

'<td><b>Description</b></td>' + '<td><b>Action By</b></td>' + '<td><b>Request From</b></td>' + '<td><b>Created</b></td>'+ 

'</tr></thead><tbody>';

function groupBy(items,propertyName)
{
    var result = [];
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
       if ($.inArray(item[propertyName], result)==-1) {
          result.push(item[propertyName]);
       }
    });
    return result;
}
function RemoveDuplicateItems(items, propertyName) {
    var result = [];
        $.each(items, function (index, item) {
            if ($.inArray(item[propertyName], result) == -1) {
                result.push(item[propertyName]);
            }
        });
    return result;
}
function ifAllCompleted() {
    for (var i=0;i<ListDataCollection.Lists.length;i++) {
     
        if (!ListDataCollection.Lists[i].Completed) {
            return false;
        }   
    }
 console.log('Completed');   
    var arrayOfAllData = ListDataCollection.Lists[0].Data.d.results;
    arrayOfAllData = arrayOfAllData.concat(ListDataCollection.Lists[1].Data.d.results);
    arrayOfAllData = arrayOfAllData.concat(ListDataCollection.Lists[2].Data.d.results);
 console.log('Total elements : ' + arrayOfAllData.length);
 arrayOfAllData=RemoveDuplicateItems(arrayOfAllData,'Description')
 for( var i=0; i<arrayOfAllData.length;i++)
 {
     tableContent += '<tr>';
                    tableContent += '<td>' + arrayOfAllData[i].Title+ '</td>';
                    tableContent += '<td>' + arrayOfAllData[i].Description+ '</td>';
                    tableContent += '<td>' + arrayOfAllData[i].Action_x0020_By_x003a_+ '</td>';
                    tableContent += '<td>' + arrayOfAllData[i].RequestFrom_x003a_+ '</td>';
     tableContent += '<td>' + arrayOfAllData[i].Created+ '</td>';
                    tableContent += '</tr>';
 }
 $('#employeeGrid').append(tableContent);
 
 
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var x=0;x<ListDataCollection.Lists.length;x++) {
        $.ajax({
            url:ListDataCollection.Lists[x].Url,
            indexValue:x,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                ListDataCollection.Lists[this.indexValue].Data = data;
                ListDataCollection.Lists[this.indexValue].Completed = true;
                ifAllCompleted();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });     
    }
});
</script>
 <div id="CustomerPanel">
        <table id="tableEmployee" border="1 px" style="width: 100%;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="employeeGrid" style="width: 100%;"><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your choice column is an object. You need to iterate over the contents of the object. For example a choice field (not a dropdown choice field) is an array of strings.

Watch/log the variable `arrayOfAllData[i].Action_x0020_By_x003a_` and you should be able to figure out how to iterate over the data.